# IPTables forward port to another ip:port but keeping original source ip

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have following iptables rules on gateway machine(192.168.0.1). I want to forward port 192.168.0.1:80 to 192.168.0.2:8080. But I need to maintain original source ip so that original server can get client ip. I have following rules but that changes client's source ip.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:8080
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.2 --dport 8080 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1
```

Are there any other rules to use in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the second line that contains the SNAT rule. That rule isn't needed.

Also how many network cards do you have? Are the two machines 192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.1 on the same network? If that is the case what route would the machine 192.168.0.2 use to forward packets that it receives on its tcp port 8080? How would it route this packet?

Comment: Removing second rule will work only for requests coming from outside network. But requests from same network doesn't work unless I add second rule.

Comment: Only gateway machine has two NIC. Web server is directly connected to gateway.